# Авторизация через Steam при Rest API на стеке React + Nest.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, steam, openid, nestjs

Я хотел бы написать web-приложение на стеке React + Node/Nest.js с авторизацией через Steam OpenID.

Дело в том что я не совсем понимаю, как это должно выглядеть по архитектуре.
Я нашел эту библиотеку: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-steam
В её примере примерно то, что мне нужно, но только там не REST API.

Мне хотелось бы узнать как вообще стоит организовывать авторизацию через third-party сервисы при REST API.
У меня в голове выглядит как-то так:
 1. Есть какой-то React компонент, который при нажатии редиректит пользователя на страницу авторизации steam.
 2. Пользователь авторизуется, а React получает токен, который отправляет на backend.
 3. Backend используя этот токен получает от third-party-serivce всё необходимую информацию, заносит её в базу, генерирует JWT и возвращает её пользователю.
 4. Фронтенд отображает успешную авторизацию.

Я бы хотел хороший гайд (в самом идеальном случае на Nest.js + React), или ссылку на ресурс, где это хорошо расписано.
Заранее спасибо.